# How will comparison operators (spaceship operator) be handled in ternary operators

Tags: ternary-operator, spaceship-operator, php-7

This question is a little preemptive, as php 7 is not even released yet. I'm curious how the spaceship operator will be handled in the context of ternary operators.

so if I have a pre-spaceship ternary expression such as:

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = 0;
echo 'foo is ' . ( ($foo > $bar) ? 'greater than' : ( ($foo < $bar ) ? 'less than' : 'equal to' ) ) . ' bar.';
```

what would be the equivalent ternary operator using a comparison operator? Are ternaries going to have some means of handling this scenario? I use ternary operators quite a lot and am curious if there is some way to streamline the code in various instances where a comparison operator would be relevant.

Comment: Stick your strings in an array, use the result of the spaceship operator (possibly adjusted by +1) to index that array?

Comment: *This question is a little preemptive* I think it's the perfect time to start NOW with asking and trying php 7 stuff. Since the release will probably be this year. So I prefer to start with php 7 now instead of waiting 5 years until everyone uses it. FYI: You can test php 7 stuff here: http://3v4l.org/ OR you can even download the php parser and install it: https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/releases/tag/v1.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaceship operator, as you can see from the documentation of [its RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator), was though mainly to be used when having to deal with orderings.

I don't think it could be of help in shortening the code that you posted, mainly beacuse the ternary operator expects a boolean value and the ternary operator returns a "true" value (1 and -1) in both cases when the the values are different. In other words, when you cast its return value to a boolean, the spaceship operator is equivalent to the != operator.

Anyway, you could experiment with it on 3v4l.org, like I did [here](http://3v4l.org/E4Bor)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clever approach for using the **spaceship operator** `<=>` as a poor man's three-way "ternary", also using an arrow function and array destructuring.

```
<?php
$relation = fn($a, $b) => [
    -1 => 'less than',
     0 => 'the same as',
     1 => 'greater than'
][$a <=> $b];

$bar = 2;

// loop $foo from 1 through 3
foreach (range(1,3) as $foo) {
  echo "foo is " . $relation($foo, $bar) . " bar.\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
foo is less than bar.
foo is the same as bar.
foo is greater than bar.
```

But watch out: it's *clever,* and clever code always requires more mental horsepower to understand, which makes it less maintainable. So there's the warning.